# Suggestion for fast performance expanding apply with deedle

Tags: f#, deedle

The `Stats.expandingXXXX` functions are pretty fast. However there is no public api to do a expandingWindow apply. The following solution i created is really slow when it comes to large dataset like 100k. Any suggestion is appreciated?

```
 let ExpWindowApply f minSize data = 
        let keys = dataSeries.Keys
        let startKey = dataSeries.FirstKey()
        let values = keys
                     |> Seq.map(fun k -> 
                                    let ds = data.Between(startKey,k) 
                                    match ds with 
                                    |_ when ds.ValueCount >= minSize -> f ds.Values
                                    |_ -> Double.NaN
                                )                     
        let result = Series(keys, values)
        result
```

I understand the Stats.expandingXXX function are actually special cases where the function being applied can be iterately calculated based on previous loop's state. And not all function can take advantage of states from previous calculation. Is there anything better way than Series.Between in terms of creating a window of data?

**Update**

For those who are also interested in the similar issue. The answer provides alternative implementation and insight into rarely documented series vector and index operation. But it doesn't improve performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expanding functions in Deedle are fast because they are using [an efficient online algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_for_calculating_variance#Online_algorithm) that makes it possible to calculate the statistics on the fly with just one pass - rather than actually building the intermediate series for the sub-ranges.

There is a built-in function `aggregate` that lets you do something this - though it works in the reversed way. For example, if you want to sum all elements starting from the current one to the end, you can write:

```
let s = series [ for i in 1 .. 10 -> i, float i ]

s |> Series.aggregateInto
        (Aggregation.WindowWhile(fun _ _ -> true))
        (fun seg -> seg.Data.FirstKey()) 
        (fun seg -> OptionalValue(Stats.sum seg.Data))
```

If you want to do the same thing using the underlying representation, you can directly use the addressing scheme that Deedle uses to link the keys (in the index) with values (in the data vector). This is an ugly mutable sample, but you can encapsulate it into something nicer:

```
[ let firstAddr = s.Index.Locate(s.FirstKey())
  for k in s.Index.KeySequence ->
    let lastAddr = s.Index.Locate(k)
    seq { 
      let a = ref firstAddr
      while !a <> lastAddr do
        yield s.Vector.GetValue(!a).Value
        a := s.Index.AddressOperations.AdjustBy(!a, +1L) } |> Seq.sum ]
```

Comment: Unfortunately, they didn't improve the performance. The first solution requires the series to be reversed and re-keyed so that it can be processed reversely to have the same result of expanding window. The second solution with some small changes to to ```!a<=lastAddr```` and handle optionalvalue missing from the vector does produce the right results. But it is slower than what i had after removing the pseq to be fair comparison.  (100k dps to calculate expanding window ECDF). But thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I guess the right approach really depends on your specific problem - the solution can be much faster if there is an online algorithm that can do it in one pass - like the built-in ones.

Comment: True. I feel pseq does a good enough job with series.Between (much better than filter). if the function can be calculated with online algo it will be really fast. This might not a fair comparison, pandas expanding apply can finish the same calculate on a single thread using only a quarter of the time. I might be wrong on this. i feel  the deedle optionalvalue, F# a' option and null made the calculation slower while Double.Nan is a valid double value for calculation.

Comment: There is definitely room for optimizations in Deedle - a faster expanding apply function sounds like a useful addition. Feel free to ping me directly (if you needed more improvements, I'm also happy to help you how to get started with contributing or I can help through some form of consulting.)